# White bar on top of the more tab view controller picker and their respective view controllers

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a tab bar with more than 5 items, when I click on the more button, it takes me to the TableViewController which has the other options but there is a white bar on top, as seen on the images below. Any view controllers which are selected from the more tab bar from there on, are all faced with the same problem of the white bar on top.

This is the screen which is shown with the visible white bar before search.

[image: The screen when more is clicked on the tab bar]

Here is the screen when I click on search, there is a white bar before the search bar.

[image: The following embedded View Controller]

Answer (score 0):

```
navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
```

**Use this in your view controllers viewdidload method**

Comment: It works when I put the code inside the view controllers which are picked. But when I click on More for the first time, it still has white spacing on top, any idea where I should place the code for that because that screen is auto generated.

Comment: open your storyboard click on navigation view controller 
in Attribute inspector there's a field know as Shows Navigation Bar 
please uncheck this.

Comment: Yeah, that disables navigation bar for the whole app, so it compromises back functionality. Is there anyway to make it specifically target a view controller?